# Regex to capture GPA with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture GPA with regex in Python. For example, I want to capture just `3.75` for both lines. The word `GPA` could be at the beginning or end of `3.75`.

```
GPA 3.75 / 4.0
3.75 / 4.0 GPA
```

`((?:gpa[ :]+)(\d\.?\d{0,2})(?:[/\d\. ]{0,6})?)|((\d\.?\d{0,2})(?:[/\d\. ]{0,6})? ?(?:gpa))`

Here is my attempt.  It works but I would like to know if there is a way not to repeat the yellow parts. They are exactly the same.

[image]

You can see more examples [here](https://regex101.com/r/0T2ZW3/1). Thanks!

Comment: You can use `re.search(r'(gpa[ :]+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?(1)| *gpa)', text, re.I).group(2)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0T2ZW3/2).

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for something like this. But this incorrectly captures `4.0` instead of `3.75` for `3.75 / 4.0 GPA`.

Comment: So, `r'(\bgpa[ :]+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[/\d\. ]{0,6})?)(?(1)| *gpa\b)'`? Or, `r'(\bgpa[ :]+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[/\d\. ]{0,6})?(?(1)| *gpa\b)'`?

Comment: Oh the second one seems to be good! Do you want to post as an answer so that I could accept yours and resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
m = re.search(r'(\bgpa[ :]+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[/\d. ]{0,6}(?(1)| *gpa\b)', text, re.I)
if m:
  print(m.group(2))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0T2ZW3/4).

*Details*:

- `(\bgpa[ :]+)?` - an optional capturing group with ID 1: a whole word `gpa` (case insensitive search is enabled via `re.I`) and then one or more spaces or colons
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Capturing group 2: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `[/\d. ]{0,6}` - zero to six `/`, digits, dots or spaces
- `(?(1)| *gpa\b)` - If Group 1 matches, match an empty string, else, match zero or more spaces and a whole word `gpa`.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BwcytH):

```py
import re
texts = ['GPA 3.75/4.00','GPA 3.75/4.0','GPA 3.75 /4.0','GPA 3.75 / 4.0','GPA 3.7 / 4      aaa','Major GPA: 3.6/4.0','GPA 3.1','GPA 3','some text GPA 3','3.25/4.0 GPA','some text 3.26 / 4.0 GPA','Minor in Art and Technology - 3.5/4.0 GPA aaaa','Minor in Art and Technology - 3.5 / 4.3 GPA aaaa']
rx = re.compile(r'(\bgpa[ :]+)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[/\d. ]{0,6}(?(1)| *gpa\b)', re.I)
for text in texts:
  m = rx.search(text)
  if m:
    print(text, "=>", m.group(2), sep=" ")
```

This outputs:

```
GPA 3.75/4.00 => 3.75
GPA 3.75/4.0 => 3.75
GPA 3.75 /4.0 => 3.75
GPA 3.75 / 4.0 => 3.75
GPA 3.7 / 4      aaa => 3.7
Major GPA: 3.6/4.0 => 3.6
GPA 3.1 => 3.1
GPA 3 => 3
some text GPA 3 => 3
3.25/4.0 GPA => 3.25
some text 3.26 / 4.0 GPA => 3.26
Minor in Art and Technology - 3.5/4.0 GPA aaaa => 3.5
Minor in Art and Technology - 3.5 / 4.3 GPA aaaa => 3.5
```

Comment: Thank you, for the capturing group 2, `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`, why do I need `?:`?

Comment: @E.K. `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) used only to group a sequence of patterns.

Comment: Yeah, for the case of `3.75`, I think `\d+` matches `3` and `(?:\.\d+)` captures `.75`, which is also a part I want to capture. So why non-capturing group for `.75`?

Comment: @E.K. Since `.75` value is not necessary in the output, there is no need allocating memory for this submatch.